# Can't use MeshLambertMaterial with custom BufferGeometry

Tags: javascript, three.js

I just wrote a simple program to generate pyramidal roof shapes in Three.js (actuall this is part of a bigger project, so I can't show you all the code). So these shapes should be rendered in the scene as well as other objects like extrusions, cubes, etc. , all in BufferGeometry and with a MeshLambertMaterial. However, the roofs I generated look as if they were generated with a MeshBasicMaterial, and I don't know why...
This is a minimal version of my code, so that you can test it :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script src="three.min.js"></script>
        <script src="OrbitControls.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            body{margin:0;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
var camera, SCENE, renderer, controls, SUN, OBJ;

init();
animate();

function init() {
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

    SCENE = new THREE.Scene();
    SCENE.background = new THREE.Color( 0xBBDDFF );

    SUN = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 0.6 );
    SCENE.add( SUN );
    SCENE.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xcccccc, 0.8 ) );


    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
    controls.minDistance = 1;
    controls.maxDistance = 1000;

    var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
    var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color:0xff0000} );
    vertices = new Float32Array([
        0,0,0,
        0,1,0,
        1,0,0,

        0,0,0,
        0,0,1,
        0,1,0,

        0,0,0,
        1,0,0,
        0,0,1,

        0,1,0,
        0,0,1,
        1,0,0,
        ]);
    geometry.addAttribute( 'position', new THREE.BufferAttribute( vertices, 3 ) );
    OBJ = new THREE.Mesh(geometry,material);
    SCENE.add(OBJ);

    camera.position.set(OBJ.position.x,10,OBJ.position.z-10);
    camera.lookAt(OBJ.position);
    controls.target.set(OBJ.position.x,1,OBJ.position.z);
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    SUN.position.copy( camera.position );
    SUN.target = OBJ;

    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    renderer.render( SCENE, camera );
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    renderer.render( SCENE, camera );
}
        </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: Often (and especially with bigger projects), creating a _minimal, complete and verifiable example_ will highlight the problem. We don't need to see all your code. Just recreate the important parts of your scene (camera, lights), and inject one of these objects. If it has the same problem, post your minimal example here, so we can see it in action.

Comment: Yes you're right, but I wanted to check if it wasn't a simple mistake before. I'll post a minimal code soon.

Answer (score 0):

You create MeshLambertMaterial in 'material' variable. But when you create your Mesh you use some 'vertexColorMaterial' variable that is not described above. Maybe that is the problem in your code?

Comment: Sorry I changed the name of the material at the last minute in my code, I correct that.